# How to write in Python NetworkX same code of R igraph

Tags: python, networkx, igraph

My teacher uses R and now he is explaining graph theory. I don't want to use R because I use Python and prefer it, so I want to learn NetworkX (**NOT** *Python igraph because I have a lot of problems printing graphs*).

The point is that the Python code seems really complicated if compared to R.

I explain myself better: how can you implement this R code

```
fig <- graph.formula(a-b, c-e-d, i-k-j-g-i, f-g-j-h-f, k-j-h-l-k, h-l-m-h)
```

on NetworkX ?

Is it possible in just one row? If not, how can I do?

thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what that R code does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly do it in networkX. I don't know if one line, but in very few.

The code below creates a directed graph with the nodes and edges you specified and then draws it. In theory, one could add all edges into one line (and there are quicker ways of doing this), but this code has one line for each comma-separated part of your R code for better readability.

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.DiGraph() #Creates empty graph
G.add_nodes_from(range(0,13))#Adds nodes
G.add_edges_from([(0,1)])#Adds directed edges
G.add_edges_from([(2,3),(3,4)])
G.add_edges_from([(8,10),(10,9),(9,6),(6,8)])
G.add_edges_from([(5,6),(6,9),(9,7),(7,5)])
G.add_edges_from([(10,9),(9,7),(7,11),(11,10)])
G.add_edges_from([(7,11),(11,12),(12,7)])
nx.draw(G)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the `igraph` documentation of [`formula`](https://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.Graph-class.html#Formula) the line you have given

```
fig <- graph.formula(a-b, c-e-d, i-k-j-g-i, f-g-j-h-f, k-j-h-l-k, h-l-m-h)
```

only creates a graph with the given (undirected) edges and nodes. So you only want to create a `graph`, you find all you need in the [`networkx` tutorial](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/tutorial.html) (`add_edges_from` method)

```py
import networks as nx

graph = nx.Graph() # undirected as desired
graph.add_edges_from([("a", "b"), ("c","e"), ("e","d"), ("i","k"), ("k", "j"), ("j", "g"), ("g", "i")])
```

As you see it's a little bit more work (I have stopped after the first three groups).